# WebBrowser SinkEvents and DesignMode = 'on'

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-2010, twebbrowser

Zarko Gajic demonstrates how to get the url of a hyperlink when the mouse moves over a TWebBrowser Document in the following article and demo:
http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/wbsinkevents.htm
This demo works well until the WebBrowser is set to designmode = 'on', then the OnMouseMove event does not execute.  Can the demo be enhanced so that the OnMouseMove event is executed when DesignMode = 'on'? If not is there a different way to create a Document.OnMouseMove event?  I am using Delphi 2010.

**[Edit]** More code was requested so here is implementation

```
procedure TForm1.DesignMode1Click( Sender: TObject );
var
  iDocument: MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  if Assigned( WebBrowser1 ) then
  begin
    iDocument := htmlDoc; //( WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2 );
    if Assigned( iDocument ) then
    begin
      if DesignMode1.Checked then
        iDocument.DesignMode := 'On'
      else
        iDocument.DesignMode := 'Off';
      WebBrowser1.Refresh2;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Document_OnMouseOver;
var
  element: IHTMLElement;
begin
  if htmlDoc = nil then
    Exit;

  element := htmlDoc.parentWindow.event.srcElement;

  elementInfo.Clear;

  if LowerCase( element.tagName ) = 'a' then
  begin
    elementInfo.Lines.Add( 'LINK info...' );
    elementInfo.Lines.Add( Format( 'HREF : %s', [ element.getAttribute( 'href', 0 ) ] ) );
  end
  else if LowerCase( element.tagName ) = 'img' then
  begin
    elementInfo.Lines.Add( 'IMAGE info...' );
    elementInfo.Lines.Add( Format( 'SRC : %s', [ element.getAttribute( 'src', 0 ) ] ) );
  end
  else
  begin
    elementInfo.Lines.Add( Format( 'TAG : %s', [ element.tagName ] ) );
  end;
end; (* Document_OnMouseOver *)

procedure TForm1.FormCreate( Sender: TObject );
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate( 'http://delphi.about.com' );
  elementInfo.Clear;
  elementInfo.Lines.Add( 'Move your mouse over the document...' );
end; (* FormCreate *)

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2( ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool );
begin
  htmlDoc := nil;
end; (* WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2 *)

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete( ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant );

begin
  if Assigned( WebBrowser1.Document ) then
  begin
    htmlDoc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    htmlDoc.onmouseover := ( TEventObject.Create( Document_OnMouseOver ) as IDispatch );
  end;
end; (* WebBrowser1DocumentComplete *)

{ TEventObject }

constructor TEventObject.Create( const OnEvent: TObjectProcedure );
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOnEvent := OnEvent;
end;

function TEventObject.GetIDsOfNames( const IID: TGUID; Names: Pointer; NameCount, LocaleID: Integer;
  DispIDs: Pointer ): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TEventObject.GetTypeInfo( Index, LocaleID: Integer; out TypeInfo ): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TEventObject.GetTypeInfoCount( out Count: Integer ): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TEventObject.Invoke( DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer; Flags: Word; var Params;
  VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer ): HResult;
begin
  if ( DispID = DISPID_VALUE ) then
  begin
    if Assigned( FOnEvent ) then
      FOnEvent;
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
    Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

end.
```

**[Fix]**
I figured out that WebBrowser1DocumentComplete was not executed after setting webbrowser to designmode so I changed DesignMode1Click and it fixed the problem.  I post this so others may see this as well:

```
procedure TForm1.DesignMode1Click( Sender: TObject );
begin
  // the following is unsafe because you may click on the
  // check box even if you don't have any page navigated
  -- htmlDoc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

  // htmlDoc will be assigned from the OnDocumentComplete
  // fired by Navigate procedure
  if Assigned( htmlDoc ) then
  begin
    if DesignMode1.Checked then
      htmlDoc.DesignMode := 'On'
    else
      htmlDoc.DesignMode := 'Off';

    // switching to design mode takes some time and if there 
    // are some pages which doesn't fire OnDocumentComplete 
    // event when you are switching to design mode, like
    // http://delphi.about.com do, then I would wait for 
    // web browser to be ready
    while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
      Application.ProcessMessages;

    // release the previous "document instance"
    htmlDoc := nil;
    // assign the new one and attach the event
    htmlDoc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    htmlDoc.OnMouseOver := ( TEventObject.Create( Document_OnMouseOver ) as IDispatch );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by setting the WebBrowser to `designmode = 'on'`?

Comment: Your question does in fact contains 2 distinct (but related) questions: It's preferable to ask under a new post the question related to the implementation of a `OnMouseMove` event

Comment: It works fine for me in D2009 (and IMHO should the same stand for D2010). Could you post here at least how you are setting the `designMode` and your `OnDocumentComplete` event handler code ?

Comment: Ok... I added an edit to show how design mode is set as well as the OnDocumentComplete from the demo at about.com.

Comment: Thanks for your help TLama.  I added the implementation section.

Comment: @TLama, See my last edit.  I figured it out.  See explanation in [Fix].  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Almost at the same time :) That's strange, I thought it is, so taking back my previous comments (it worked for me but with my testing web pages, `delphi.about.com` really doesn't fire `OnDocumentComplete` when you switch `designMode`). And I would modify your code a little bit...

Comment: @TLama, What would you modify?

Comment: See my edit in your question ;)

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your solution as the answer. I'll vote you up ;)

Comment: I suggest you to migrate the solution as answer. It's still listed as **unanswered question**. Follow @TLama's advice.

Comment: who is TEventObject ???